# Is it possible to Update single/multiple columns using "group by"

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am running group by on 4 columns of two tables. I have unique ID column in two tables. I want to mark both the tables occurrences column to SINGLE/MULTIPLE based on the 4 columns. Is there any way to update based on the results of group by?.

Comment: your question is too hard to understand. please provide example input rows and an example of the desired output. and the query you already have.

Answer (score 1):

As longneck noted, your description is pretty vague.

However, to answer your question generally, it IS possible to run an update based on the results of another query:

```
UPDATE your_update_table
FROM your_update_table
JOIN
(
    # Insert your query (with GROUP BYs and all) here
) AS subquery_join ON subquery_join.id = your_update_table.id
SET your_update_table.column = subquery_join.some_value
```

A more explicit answer would require a more detailed explanation of the problem.